# Finding result of POST in Http Response Message

Tags: c#, rest, httpresponse

I am building REST Client (c#) using windows form application in VS2017. I have been able to successfully GET and POST requests from the server using the HttpClient.PostAsJsonAsync() and ReadAsync() methods. I am trying to POST some data to the server and upon a successful POST, the server responds with a unique string like **"1c77ad2e-54e0-4187-aa9d-9a55286b1f7a"**

I get a successful response code (200 - OK) for the POST. However, I am not sure where to check for the resulting string. I have checked the contents of HttpResponseMessage.Content

```
static async Task<HttpStatusCode> PostBurstData(string path, BurstRequest 
burstRequest)
    {
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync(path, burstRequest);

        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        Console.WriteLine(response.Content.ToString());

        // return response
        return response.StatusCode;
    }
```

The data sent to this function call is as follows:

```
BurstRequest request = new BurstRequest();
            request.NodeSerialNumbers = SubSerialList;
            request.StartTime = ((DateTimeOffset)dateTimePicker1.Value).ToUnixTimeMilliseconds();

            HttpStatusCode statusCode = new HttpStatusCode();

            statusCode = await PostBurstData(post_burst_url, request);
```

Where should I search for the string the server responds for a successful POST? Should the content be read using ReadAsync()?

```
if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var data = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync();

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not trying to use `HttpContent` like below:

```
using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url)) // here you can use your own implementation i.e PostAsJsonAsync
        {
            using (HttpContent content = response.Content)
            {
                string responseFromServer = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            }

        }
```